# How to define a point of crashing in a C software

Tags: c, networking

First : Appologize for my bad english.

Sorry for this newbie software question, but I got lost with my own logic...

A bit background :

I am working on a C networking project, where I am trying to generate a server that receive gradually increasing UDP message within the increasing time. I am trying just to simple "manager" on this server that is able to send a report to a specific address when it is crashing.

The thing that come in mind is that I set this manager as a listener in the server side. So if the server does not receive any message within the predefined port, I assume the server fails. 
But, this thing is not -somehow- a deterministic approach. How long should I specify the time if this server crash? (if in 5 minutes no message is received in the port, does it mean it is crashing? not necessarly true. I can again increase it to 10 mins, buat again, this is unjustiable and inconsistent)

I am thinking how an app like gdb can do this. If the server(framework) crash, it will automatically generate a coredump file. I need to do a similar thing like this, so when the framework crash, it will as easy as print a "hello crash". How to create a "manager" on the server that can give me a report if the server crash (using C )

Any idea would be greatly appreciated

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you mean a *crash* (the application unexpectedly exits), or a *hang* (application stops responding, but does not exit)?

Comment: Also, would you define "losing network connection" as crashing?

Comment: @wallyk : as in unexpectedly exists..

Comment: @heike: Is your question about how a remote UDP client can know the server is not there or about how a program on the server machine could watch the server program to see if it crashes?

Comment: @BenJackson : sorry for the confussion. I need a program in the server that could watch if it crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit code of a process tells you if a signal caused it to exit.  You can write a C program and use `wait()` to get the exit code or do it in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

./server "$@"

EXIT=$?

if [ $EXIT -eq 0 ]
then
    echo exit success
else
    if [ $EXIT -ge 128 ]
    then
        echo exited with signal $(($EXIT - 128))
    else
        echo exited with code $EXIT
    fi
fi
```

You could choose to restart the server for the failure case or the signal case.

Most servers rely on careful debugging and do not expect to automatically catch and restart when they crash.

Comment: This answer assumes the server is running something POSIX-ish. A fair assumption given that GCC is involved, but worth pointing out anyway.

Comment: @ben jackson : thanks. but can you tell me what is exit -128. I can not find it anywhere..

Comment: @heike I should have pointed out the `wait()` manpage (see eg http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait ) which explains the macros `WIFSIGNALED()` and friends.  In my shell example I'm testing (and then unsetting) bit `0x80` in a way you wouldn't see in a C program.